# customize welcome card from website discord.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, discord, dashboard

I have a discord bot and I need to make a dashboard for it.
But how to make welcome cards with canvas (every guild have its own background) which user can control the avatar and username position by mouse to be consistent with the background like mee6 or probot

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know this isnt sorta what your looking for but I recently disccorveed an api that does welcome cards.
Here's the link to it, [popcat api](https://api.popcat.xyz/welcomecard?background=https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/850808002545319957/859359637106065408/bg.png&text1=Zero%20Two&text2=Welcome+To+Pop+Cat+Community&text3=Member+219&avatar=https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png)
You can change the text and stuff via the url. Lmk if this helped!
[image]